# React router, pass props with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using React Router to navigate to a page in my app like this:

```
<Link to={`/single/${this.props.data.pageId}`} params={{singleId: 1}}>GotoPage!</Link>
```

This works fine but I would also like to pass an additional property to the new page.

When rendering a component without using Link I would do something like:

```
<MyComponent myProp={this.props.data}/>
```

I have tried passing `myProp={this.props.data}` along in params like this:

```
<Link to={`/single/${this.props.data.pageId}`} params={{singleId: 1, myProp={this.props.data}}}>GotoPage!</Link>
```

But it does not seem to work as myProp is undefined on the new page as oppose to   pageId which I can get like:

```
this.props.params.pageId;
```

Am I not supposed to be able to pass non-route related parameters with `Link`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link) for `Link` and also the source, there's no mention of it taking `param`. But I get what you're trying to do.

Instead of hard-coding routes, may I recommend using react-router's history function `router.push()`. Do something like this instead:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  ...
  const handleNewRoute = () => {
     let { pageId } = this.props.data
     let singleId = '1'
     this.context.router.push({    // use push
       pathname: `/single/${pageId}`,
       query: { singleId }
     })
  }

  render() {
     return (
         <button onLeftClick={this.handleNewRoute} />
     )
  }
}
```

By the way, in React/JSX, something like `...{{singleId: 1, myProp={this.props.data}}}...` should be `<Link...foobar={{singleId: 1, myProp: this.props.data}}>`. The former syntax is wrong.

Comment: This worked! I had to change  this.context.router.push to  this.context.history.push which seems to be the new syntax for v.2
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to get the additional data is an ajax.

But if you want your way to do this,I check the api of Link and I find a query property.

```
query:

An object of key:value pairs to be stringified.
```

so you can use this to pass a object of key:value to the next route,but this object will be stringified and passed though the url I think.I prefer an ajax for this.

Comment: can you give an example of use of ajax in this scenario